# Wait for previous execution before running next one?

Tags: javascript

I have long-running function that can be called several times in short period of time. I dont realy need to await her, so I want following: If previous instance of function is still running, next runs should wait for previous one to finish.

Simplest/correct way to solve?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a tiny package called [`mutually-exclusive-functions`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mutually-exclusive-functions) that is capable of doing what you want.

```js
const { exclude } = require("mutually-exclusive-functions");

async function f1() {};

[f1] = exclude([f1]);
```

Now if you execute `f1`, it will queue further calls and only execute them after the previous calls have finished execution.